# Angular Service & parent-child Component Communication

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular-services, angular-components

Which is the preferred approach when using depdency injection and multiple component?

Option1: Angular parent component talks with service (DI) for data and passing the data to child components?

Option2: All child component and parent component talk to the service for data ?

Answer (score 1):

Preferance is based on cases in application. If components are unrelated, then service is better approach.  If components are related then use parent child communication.

**child component is a componet that is a part of one page. If you don't want to writes a lot of codes in just one component which is diffucult to read for another developers you should pair it to sub components.So it will be readable for another developers in the future too**

1. For example;You have one data then u will visualize this with table
   and charts. Then approach is use two child components for chart and
   table and show them in one page.
2. Another example; you have two pages and both pages have logics itself one
   component need one id from another then use service to send another
   component.

Comment: My problem is, both the components is in the same page and use the same data

Comment: okey if they are at same page then there will be one parent component for them then parent child communication u have take datas from child to main parent and send to another child from parent